# Transaction bug for calling a function without the final 0 in an address?

Tags: solidity, transactions

I'm trying to test the article at https://blog.golemproject.net/how-to-find-10m-by-just-reading-blockchain-6ae9d39fcd95, which suggests that for a function that takes an ethereum address as its first parameter and then a uint value as its second parameter, if the function is called with an address ending in 0 (but without entering the final 0) the value of the uint parameter will be shifted to the left and the value made larger.

I have the following function:

```
function sendether (address to, uint value) {
    to.send(value);
}
```

And an address `0x196218dc0f59bd7247b5c10f97cdc503d7c8cb80` (ending in 0).

Calling my function as follows, for example (omitting the final 0 in my address):

`contractInstance.sendether("0x196218dc0f59bd7247b5c10f97cdc503d7c8cb8", 10, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:4000000}`

Actually sends the 10 wei to address `0x0196218dc0f59bd7247b5c10f97cdc503d7c8cb8` instead (the missing 0 is added at the start, right after 0x, instead of the end).

And results in the following transaction:

`0xac3701990000000000000000000000000196218dc0f59bd7247b5c10f97cdc503d7c8cb8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a`

If I were to call the function with the correct address (0 at the end) as follows:

`contractInstance.sendether("0x196218dc0f59bd7247b5c10f97cdc503d7c8cb80", 10, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:4000000}`

It has the following transaction:

`0xac370199000000000000000000000000196218dc0f59bd7247b5c10f97cdc503d7c8cb80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a`

The right side of these two transactions (...000000a) which represents the `uint value` is the same, and both just send 10 wei. I am wondering if (per the article) there is still a vulnerability here and a function that takes an address as a parameter should verify it's an address of the right length.